# PHP - Find occurence in array and then place the replaced part at the start

Tags: php

Here is my code:

```
function TranslatedTitle($Title) {
ConnectWithMySQLDatabase();

    $v = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `ProductTranslations`");
    while($vrowis = mysql_fetch_array($v)){

            $English[] = $vrowis['English'];
            $Bulgarian[] = $vrowis['Bulgarian'];
    }

    $TranslatedTitle = str_replace($English, $Bulgarian, $Title);

return $TranslatedTitle;
}
```

I am using this code to fetch data from MySQL table and then search for certain phrase in English and then replace it with the phrase setted to replace the English one with the Bulgarian one.

Example:

`I have very big blue eyes.`
Will be translated to:
`I have very големи сини eyes` . It takes the phrase `big blue` and replace it with `големи сини` at the position where it can be found.

In other words how can i make the replaced part to be moved in the beginning of the string giving final result by my example as `големи сини I have very eyes`.

The sentence in the example have no meaning but i have created it as an example.

Comment: Stop using the **deprecated and as of PHP7 removed** `mysql_*` functions. Migrate to PDO and start using Prepared Statements.

Comment: Well, if you were really Tony Stark, you a) wouldn't use mysql_* b) wouldn't ask for help c) already know the answer

Comment: @CharlotteDunois i haven't received any more helpful post in my whole expericnce in StackOverflow. You have made my day. Thanks for the help and for pointing the obvious. I am not using this in a production website. I am making some tests.

Comment: I'm not sure, do you want the bulgarian at the position of the english phrase or at the beginning of the string? Your question is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try looping through the `$English` array and when finding the matching word move it to the beginning, then translating... something like:

```
foreach($English as $word){
   $pos = strpos($Title, $word);

   if ($pos !== false) {
      //english word found
      $Title = $word . str_replace($English, '', $Title);
      break;
   }
}
```

Then

```
$TranslatedTitle = str_replace($English, $Bulgarian, $Title);
```

Comment: actually it need to replace with "" instead of space. This will prevent huge space gap within the text.

Comment: By your answer i receive the following:  `Array I have very eyes`

Comment: @TonyStark see my answer as well as steps to get it work.

Comment: It has to be in the `while` loop and use the columns from the table directly.

Comment: If $Bulgarian is an array you could use the implode function:

`implode(" ", $Bulgarian);`

Comment: @KemoyCampbell even inside the while loop the result is the same. Not working in that way.

Comment: @TonyStark.... I noticed that you have been told many times to use PDO instead of mysql_ extensions since 2015. What is the hold up and stubbornness?

Comment: Again not working becuase now it is placing all the info infront of the string making huge results.

Comment: "Placing all of the info" What do you mean by this? `$Bulgarian` is an Array, what does the array contain?

Comment: `$Bularian` contains all of the possible translations I take it?

Comment: It is not placing in the front of the string the replaced part but it is placing all the "search" strings.

Comment: Yes @ShawnNorthrop it contains all the possible translations.

Comment: Hmm... interesting situation... Will it only replace 1 occurance per `$Title` or will there be multiple ie. `I have very big blue eyes and short brown hair` == `I have very … eyes and … brown hair`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122054/discussion-between-shawn-northrop-and-tony-stark).

Answer (score 0):

First off, you will want to use PDO to interact with your database. mysql_ extensions are now deprecated, bad practice and vulnerable to sql injections. You can manipulate your strings using strpos see php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php. You will want to first go like this: find the text to replace, translate, remove the word from where ever it is by using $strip = str_replace("",$word) and finally append your result to a new variable ike this $variable = $translate.$strip . Hope that helps